# ibm as400 model 9406-270

Tags: ibm-server, mainframe

I'm a fan of the mainframe world, I've always played with a mainframe emulated by Hercules, yesterday I had the opportunity to buy a used as400, I got all the cables and etc.
Now I need to know how to access the mainframe with terminal...

This is the inputs that the as400 have:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the operating system is.... :(, I just know that it is not linux the operating system..... about the terminal, I want to use some windows/linux terminal... so, if I can connect using a TCP/IP or COM port, will be nice... but, for this, I need to know what exactly is this ports...

Comment: really, I know the question is comprehensive but, like I said, I've always used an emulated mainframe, I've never used the physical computer...

Comment: I was able to turn the system on and off successfully, I listen to the starting HD and etc... so, I believe you have accessed the correct ipl

Comment: I turned on the system, and changed the ipl from control panel.... I used the IPL mode B, to enter in production mode

Comment: To power on, I used the options: 02 B N

Comment: This doesn't really qualify as a PC.  I'm wondering if Server Fault would be a better site for this.

Comment: @fixer1234 Server Fault might be better, but nowhere in "What topics can I ask about" does it mention that this site is limited to PC's. It specifically says questions about computer hardware are acceptable, and how to connect a console to an AS/400 is very much a computer hardware question.

Comment: @fixer1234 Of course due to the age of that model and the last version of the OS it supports, maybe Retrocomputing would be even better!

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations !

That connector left of J11, is a serial port connector. Connecting to an AS/400 w/o a monitor is similar to connecting to a Cisco device using the same terminal emulator like Hercules.

A decent 10 minute video on the process is at youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qPHXFzWtZI

I would highly recommend a decent Null Modem/USB adapter, I use this $20 StarTech from Amazon and it's always served me well:
[https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-USB-Serial-Adapter-Modem/dp/B008634VJY/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008634VJY)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm really very happy for my purchase!! .... I have a cable that converts from this input circled in red ( https://i.imgur.com/ryXBXH1.jpg ), to serial, you know to tell me exactly what it is, I'm guessing this output can also be for the terminal?

Comment: The connector in that image is not a serial connection.  You will want to use a USB to Serial cable instead.

Comment: @Alexandre -That second circled image in red is your TokenRing network adapter. TR CAN run on CAT3/5/6 Ethernet cables but it was as (un)common as Super VHS. I don't know if there is a method to connect your terminal emu via Token Ring.

Comment: I'm with a null modem cable now, but, when I connected to as400, nothing appers, you know if it's possible to be some internal video redirection ? ( maybe for the 2746 card... )

Comment: Did you set your terminal emulator at 9600kbs, 8 bits, no parity and 1?

Comment: Yeap!... i tested with 3 different prograns to connect to serial port

Comment: And you watched and followed the YouTube video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qPHXFzWtZI and followed his instructions, configure the COM port, set the BAUD rate?

Comment: or, maybe my null modem cable is faulty... I did a lot of tests, with different options

Comment: I forwarded a YT vid, I just asked again and you still didn't answer if you followed the i-n-s-t-r-u-c-t-i-o-n's in the video, he walks you through the installation of your Null modem cable, determining COM ports, setting baud rates, it's all significant. Here's some more homework on your behalf, try this emu http://tn5250j.sourceforge.net/   but at this moment I'm exhausted. Congrats on your AS/400, you're a real enterprise computer owner now.

Comment: Yes, I followed the instructions, several times !, to make sure I was doing it right! :)